# Using connected animation

Tags: c#, uwp

```
        <GridView x:Name="ForegroundElement" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Icons}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Grid_Clicked">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Icon">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image x:Name="ConnectedElement" Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{x:Bind ImageCover}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Room}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

this is my gridView contain the data 
and this is my clicked event

```
    private void Grid_Clicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var icon = (Icon)e.ClickedItem;
        IconResult.Text = "You selected a " + icon.Title;

    }
```

I wanna add the ConnectedAnimation when ever I click a "Stack" in the "GridView" to navigate the other page 
Microsoft I have to create the "PrepareConnectedAnimation" method use this 
but in my case I have a click event so what should I do to create and use this method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly ok to put it inside the `Clicked` event. You first have to get hold of the item container itself. You can do that using the `ContainerFromItem` method of the `GridView`:

```
private void Grid_Clicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var icon = (Icon)e.ClickedItem;
    IconResult.Text = "You selected a " + icon.Title;

    var container = ForegroundElement.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
    if (container != null)
    {
        //find the image
        var root = (FrameworkElement)container.ContentTemplateRoot;
        var image = (UIElement)root.FindName("ConnectedElement");

        //prepare the animation
        ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("Image", image);
    }

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
}
```

Now on the second page you get hold of the animation and connect it:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    ConnectedAnimation imageAnimation =
        ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("Image");
    imageAnimation?.TryStart(TargetElement);
}
```

You can [check out the exmple](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/ConnectedAnimationSample) provided in the UWP Samples gallery on GitHub to see full implementation in action.

Comment: my system said ConnectedAnimationService does not exist in the current content

Comment: `ConnectedAnimation` and `ConnectedAnimationService` were introduced in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (14393). Make sure your app's minimum target version is at least that. Also include `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation` at the top of your class to include the required namespace.

Comment: my minimum version is build 16299

Comment: In such case the API must be there. Try to write the class name in full: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ConnectedAnimationService`

Comment: Happy to help :-) . If that resolves your problem, please accept the answer to close it. Happy coding!

Comment: and Whai is TargetElement in your case is ?

Comment: The `TargetElement` is the element on the second page where you are navigating (the one with which you are connecting the animation)

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot connect from phone. You can update the question with the code you want to check

Comment: It's look like the detail page (the second page) cannot pick up my c# data (icon)

Comment: I add an Image with a source="{x:Bind Imagecover}" like the first page, It wasn't found

Comment: You need to get hold of the icon on the second page somehow. You can use the second parameter of `Frame.Navigate` to pass the identifier there. Please check the sample, they implement very similar scenario https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/ConnectedAnimationSample

Comment: Oh I see It's work. OMG you just save my life, Thanks buddy. Ok there would be a few step can you stick with me ?

Comment: You should accept this answer and create a another one if you have a different problem :-) . You can post its URL here so I know where to look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181585/use-case-switch-in-c-sharp

Comment: Huston we got a problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184040/cant-make-connected-animation-navigate-back

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the latest issue somehow? I am interested if you found a solution somehow?

Comment: Nope Iam still stuck and really struggling, I just dont know why it doesnt work

Comment: It is very strange. I will try to use the connected animations on a simple project and write a blog post if I find a solution

Comment: It just creating another Connected Animation like the first ? But why it doesnt work this time ?

Comment: Because connected animations don't work when navigating back, only when navigating forward.

Comment: really? I dont see Microsoft warn me that. Are you creating that project right now ohhhh I love to see you make work

Comment: Microsoft use the "OnNavigateFrom" method to prepair the animation from the detail page and "Grid_onLoad" to start the animation in the MainPage

Comment: Hey Martin did you build your own solution yet ?

Comment: Martin ? :( Iam stuck with this like 28hours

Comment: Oh my, I completely missed it

Comment: You should use code similar to the GridView_Loaded method in the example. Apparently you need to connect the animation going backward as well

Comment: Ideally as a Stack Overflow question so that others may be help as well

Comment: Iam gonna make another question about this topic ? Should that be ok ?

Comment: Definitely that will be great :-)

Comment: Unlucky for me I cant post any question anymore

Comment: Alright I have found out the solution 
I tested on another project the connected Animation working find (we have to set the second one though) but what we dealing hear is a grid view not a "single image" so the MainPage doesnt know which one to start

Comment: I really hope you can reply soon Martin. Because you are the only one who could say me now

Comment: Hi sorry, I didn't get a chance to create a test project yet... Why can't you post a new question? Have you tried again today? It would be best

Comment: Stackoverflow wont let me create another question :(

Comment: It should be possible after a few hours again, what is the error?

Comment: We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. :'(

Comment: Could you send me the whole project somehow? It is very hard to fix like this and I still need to do other work :-)

Comment: Iam completely banded from this :)). Give me your Gmail I will send all the project to you

Comment: I don't want to post it here publicly. Write me a private message on Twitter, or on Facebook, my name is @MZetko on both

Comment: Ive send a message to your facebook